# WPF: Get control from ListView DataTemplate in Code Behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've created a ListView with a selfmade ItemTemplate, that is quite nested:

```
<ListView x:Name="QuestionListView" ItemsSource="{Binding QuestionList, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Background="#afafaf" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="0,5,0,0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="8*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="15,0,0,15" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" Background="#676767" />
                    <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="0,3,1,3" Background="#8f8f8f" />
                    <Border Grid.Column="2" CornerRadius="0,15,15,0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray" Background="#676767" />

                    <Label Content="{Binding ID}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="40" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Beige" />

                    <!--This is the TextEditor, I need in my Code behind-->
                    <Viewbox Grid.Column="1">
                        <avalonEdit:TextEditor xmlns:avalonEdit="http://icsharpcode.net/sharpdevelop/avalonedit" Name="textEditor" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="600" FontSize="30" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" Foreground="Beige" PreviewLostKeyboardFocus="RichTextBox_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus" FontFamily="Consolas">
                            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <beh:AvalonEditBehaviour GiveMeTheText="{Binding TextQuestion, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        </avalonEdit:TextEditor>
                    </Viewbox>

                <!--<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" IsHitTestVisible="False" FontSize="25" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="LightGray" Text="Your question here" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                    <TextBlock.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TextQuestion, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBlock.Style>
                </TextBlock>-->

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Button Margin="10,0,5,0" Width="40" Height="40" Background="Gray" Command="{Binding EditCommand}" MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave">
                        <Image Source="{Binding EditImage}" />
                    </Button>
                    <Button Margin="5,0,10,0" Width="40" Height="40" Background="Gray" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}">
                        <Image Source="{Binding DeleteImage}" />
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Now I want to get the TextEditor `textEditor` in my code behind, because I need it for the "Intellisense" window, I am customizing.

So I have this in my Code behind:

```
public partial class QuestionListUC : UserControl
{
    TextEditor editor;

    public QuestionListUC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var template = QuestionListView.Template;
        editor = (TextEditor)template.FindName("textEditor", QuestionListView);
    }
}
```

But the FindName-Method outputs nothing for me, the variable "editor" is null.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get a ViewBox around the Editor and then just use it's child. now I have the control in my CB

Answer (score 0):

```
     private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            var template = QuestionListView.ItemTemplate;
            editor = (TextEditor)template.FindName("textEditor", 
                   QuestionListView);
            }), DispatcherPriority.DataBind);
     }
```

This should work

The most important change is

```
var template = QuestionListView.ItemTemplate;
```

The Dispatcher just delays the action until the data binding has been done, so the ItemTemplate should not be null

Comment: Well, now it crashes with the message that "This operation is valid only on elements that have this template applied."

Comment: on which line does it crash?

Comment: When it calls FindName. When I don't cast, and just do `var editor = template.FindName("textEditor", QuestionListView);`, then `editor`hasn't changed. (I created a new empty object outside the dispatcher and later attached the value from FindName to it), in the end, the new object was still just an empty object)